# Kotlin while loop not working with three conditons

Tags: sorting, kotlin

I'm trying to sort product elements with ascending price if there stock is not equal to 0.

When i use `while (j >= 0  && keyElement.stock > 0 && list[j].price > keyElement.price)`
it return list as it is without sorting.

```
data class Product(
    val name: String,
    val price: Int,
    val stock: Int
)
```

```
fun main() {

    val list = mutableListOf(
        Product("Product_001", 199, 8),
        Product("Product_002", 180, 0),
        Product("Product_003", 180, 0),
        Product("Product_004", 180, 2),
        Product("Product_005", 210, 6),
    )

    for (i in list.indices) {
        val keyElement = list[i]
        var j = i - 1
        while (j >= 0  && keyElement.stock > 0 && list[j].price > keyElement.price){
            list[j+1] = list[j]
            --j
        }
        list[j+1] = keyElement
    }

    list.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

i want to sort product list like this

```
Product(name=Product_004, price=180, stock=2)
Product(name=Product_001, price=199, stock=8)
Product(name=Product_005, price=210, stock=6)
Product(name=Product_002, price=180, stock=0)
Product(name=Product_003, price=180, stock=0)
```

Comment: Is this for practicing sorting algorithms or you are just not aware that there are a ready to use sorting utils in stdlib?

Comment: both! Actually i want to sort price if its stock is not zero. i can use `list.sort()` but i will sort every element according to price without checking stock.

Comment: @KunalSharma it depends on how you define comparability of your elements. You can make `Product` implement the `Comparable` interface and and use both stock and price in your implementation of `compareTo`. Or you can use Kotlin's `sortWith`/`sortBy` (instead of just `sort()`) and provide functions that take into account stock and price without `Product` even being comparable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list.sortBy { if (it.stock == 0) Int.MAX_VALUE else it.price }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using already existing sorting utils, instead of your own implementation, you can do this with:

```
list.sortWith(
    compareBy<Product> { -it.stock.sign }
        .thenBy { it.price }
)
```

It has a little drawback that it sorts products with 0 stocks as well. If this is undesirable, we can improve this, but the code will be a little less readable.

And if you are interested what was wrong with your code, the bug was here:

```
list[j].price > keyElement.price
```

It allows to swap elements only if the price is bigger, even if `list[j].stock` is 0. So it still takes into account the price of products that are out of stock. You need to replace it with:

```
(list[j].stock == 0 || list[j].price > keyElement.price)
```

Comment: @KunalSharma the main problem in your code is that it's harder to reason about and spot what is wrong with it when you compare it to built-in solutions like this :)

Comment: @broot I usually prefer this kind of 2-step approach where you clearly identify that you sort first by one thing and then by another. But in this specific case, I prefer @IR42's alternative for 2 reasons: 1) the use of `sign` here doesn't really reflect intent, it's more about 0 vs non-0, and 2) it's just simpler with `sortBy`. It really reflects how we're sorting

Comment: @Joffrey  i'm not comparing these answer with mine, actually i'm trying to figure out what is wrong in it so next time i'll try to avoid this mistake ;)

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the bug in your code. And Joffrey didn't write to you, but to me. He is right, solution of IR42 seems better than above. I thought it will be less readable to create a comparator for two props manually, but this is not really the case here :-)

Comment: @broot `(list[j].stock == 0 || list[j].price > keyElement.price)` getting same unsorted list :'(

Comment: Hmm... could you recheck? I tested this and it worked for me. Just to make sure we are on the same page, I'm talking about leaving everything as was in your original code, but replacing `while` with: `while (j >= 0  && keyElement.stock > 0 && (list[j].stock == 0 || list[j].price > keyElement.price))`

Comment: Yup! working fine Thanks @broot u r awesome ;)